# A-Frame scene initializes before assets ready when dynamically adding `a-asset-item` elements

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have published an A-Frame component `street` ([source](https://github.com/kfarr/streetmix3d/blob/master/src/components/street.js)) that depends on many assets to construct a streetscape.

I have followed a working example from another A-Frame component app [vartiste-toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-vartiste-toolkit) to inject `a-asset-item` elements dynamically prior to scene initialization. The goal is to use the A-Frame asset loader (and display its built-in loading screen) while also allowing a simple syntax for other developers to include this component in their scene, such as:

```
<a-assets>
  <a-asset streetmix-assets-url="https://kfarr.github.io/streetmix3d/"></a-asset>
</a-assets>
```

I have created a test project that loads the component and assets in that fashion:

https://street-component-test.glitch.me

The assets and scene load as expected on the first page load when when loading all files new (no locally cached files). It looks like the "desired state" screenshot below.

However, on the second or subsequent loads (which use cached files) I am having an issue where some entities do not load as expected. It looks like the "error state" screenshot below.

In the "error state" scene the console includes many of these errors:
`THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is incomplete`

My hypothesis is that when loading the scene with locally cached files, the A-Frame scene initializes prior to the `street` component assets being injected into the `a-assets` section. This results in entities being acted on prior to their underlying textures being ready for scene to start rendering, and thus the above THREE console error.

How can I ensure "desired state" outcome even when loading with cached files?

Is there a better way to allow users to load a set of assets required for a component?

---

Screenshots:

Desired state:
[image: screenshot of correctly loading street]

Error state:
[image: screenshot of not correctly loading street]

Comment: it works ok in firefox but on chrome Desired state works on first load but after refresh it shows the error state, just sharing. If might be there is an issue with the model object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to create a custom `A-Node` element. Let's call it `streetmix-assets`. As long as we attach the `streetmix-assets` to the `a-assets` element before it has finished loading, we can force `a-assets` to wait for all of the rest of the assets to load.

There's two tricky parts here:

1. Convince `a-assets` to wait for `streetmix-assets` to finish loading.
2. Prevent `streetmix-assets` from loading until all of the assets we inject have finished loading.

We handle **1** by masquerading `streetmix-assets` as an `a-asset-item` entity (e.g., set `isAssetItem = true` and add a `src` attribute). We can handle **2** by reusing the methods of `a-assets` itself. The code to register the `streetmix-assets` element is below:

```js
// Avoid adding everything twice
var alreadyAttached = false;
  
// Needed to masquerade as an a-assets element
var fileLoader = new THREE.FileLoader();
  
window.AFRAME.registerElement('streetmix-assets', {
  prototype: Object.create(window.AFRAME.ANode.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() {
        // Masquerade as a an a-asset-item so that a-assets will wait for it to load
        this.setAttribute('src', '')
        this.isAssetItem = true;
        
        // Properties needed for compatibility with a-assets prototype
        this.isAssets = true;
        this.fileLoader = fileLoader;
        this.timeout = null;
      }
    },
    attachedCallback: {
      value: function () {
        if (alreadyAttached) return;
        if (this.parentNode && this.parentNode.hasLoaded) console.warn("Assets have already loaded. streetmix-assets may have problems")
        
        alreadyAttached = true;
        
        // Set the innerHTML to all of the actual assets to inject
        this.innerHTML = buildAssetHTML(this.getAttribute("url"));
        
        var parent = this.parentNode
        
        // Copy the parent's timeout, so we don't give up too soon
        this.setAttribute('timeout', parent.getAttribute('timeout'))
        
        // Make the parent pretend to be a scene, since that's what a-assets expects
        this.parentNode.isScene = true
        
        // Since we expect the parent element to be a-assets, this will invoke the a-asset attachedCallback, 
        // which handles waiting for all of the children to load. Since we're calling it with `this`, it 
        // will wait for the streetmix-assets's children to load
        Object.getPrototypeOf(parent).attachedCallback.call(this)
        
        // No more pretending needed
        this.parentNode.isScene = false
      }
    },
    load: {
      value: function() {
        // Wait for children to load, just like a-assets
        AFRAME.ANode.prototype.load.call(this, null, function waitOnFilter (el) {
          return el.isAssetItem && el.hasAttribute('src');
        });
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Some quick notes about this first snippet:

- `buildAssetHTML(assetUrl)` is a function that returns a string containing the HTML code for all of your assets. (E.g., something like `<img src="myimage.jpg><a-asset src="my-asset.glb></a-asset>` etc.)
- `this.getAttribute("url")` allows the user to specify the url to load the assets from. So it can be used like: `<streetmix-asset url="http://mycdn.example.com/streetmix"></streetmix-asset>`
- `alreadyAttached` protects against accidentally adding the streetmix assets multiple times.

This snippet should get you to the point where a user can include your library and then put:

```html
<a-assets>
  <streetmix-asset></streetmix-asset>
</a-assets>
```

in their own scene to properly load your assets. However, if the user does not include the `streetmix-assets` element, then your assets will not load.

In order to ensure that your assets load no matter what (i.e. the intention behind the assets in *aframe-vartiste-toolkit*) there are three cases to consider:

1. The user has included the `a-assets` element *and* the `streetmix-assets` element.
2. The user has included neither the `a-assets` element *nor* the `streetmix-assets` element.
3. The user has included the `a-assets` element *but not* the `streetmix-assets` element.

The first case is already taken care of by registering the element. The second case could be handled in a fairly straightforward way by listening for the `DOMContentLoaded`, e.g.:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => { 
  if (alreadyAttached) return;
  let assets = document.querySelector('a-assets')
  if (!assets)
  {
    assets = document.createElement('a-assets')
    document.querySelector('a-scene').append(assets)
  }
  
  if (assets.hasLoaded)
  {
    console.warn("Assets already loaded. May lead to bugs")
  }
  
  let streetMix = document.createElement('streetmix-assets')
  assets.append(streetMix)
});
```

However, in case 3 this would run into the same problem you're experiencing now, since the `a-assets` may have already finished loading by the time `DOMContentLoaded` is emitted. So we'll forget about the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Instead, we'll tackle case 2 and case 3 at the same time, using the `DOMSubtreeModified` event. We can use the `DOMSubtreeModified` to add the `streetmix-assets` element as soon as the `a-scene` is in place. The code for this looks something like this:

```js
var domModifiedHandler = function(evt) {
  // Only care about events affecting an a-scene
  if (evt.target.nodeName !== 'A-SCENE') return;
  
  // Try to find the a-assets element in the a-scene
  let assets = evt.target.querySelector('a-assets');  
  
  if (!assets) {
    // Create and add the assets if they don't already exist
    assets = document.createElement('a-assets')
    evt.target.append(assets)
  }
  
  // Already have the streetmix assets. No need to add them
  if (assets.querySelector('streetmix-assets')) {
    document.removeEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", domModifiedHandler);
    return
  }
  
  // Create and add the custom streetmix-assets element
  let streetMix = document.createElement('streetmix-assets')
  assets.append(streetMix)
  
  // Clean up by removing the event listener
  document.removeEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", domModifiedHandler);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", domModifiedHandler, false);
```

All of this should allow you to inject your assets from an included library into a user's scene pretty reliably. Just take note that this solution leans pretty heavily on some A-Frame implementation details that could change in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

Like You say, there is a race between the script which injects assets into the document and the component which uses them

One solution would be to keep the information whether the assets are injected and use it in the said component:

```
// - assetsloaded can be a global flag, assets dataset attribute
// a-frame component / system attribute.
// - streetmix-assets-load can be an event emitted on the <a-assets> node
if (assetsloaded)
   parseResponse(response)
else
   assets.addEventListener("streetmix-assets-loaded", e => parseResponse(response))
```

You can see a similar approach [here in aframe-extras](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/controls/movement-controls.js#L44-L48).

---

You can modify `assets.js` to keep the info whether `streetmix-assets` are ready, emit a `streetmix-assets-loaded`, and make sure that the `street` component does its job when the assets are ready.

Like in [this glitch](https://stack-64841550.glitch.me/), which is a remix of your glitch, where I've applied said logic in `assets.js` and `street.js`.

Comment: Do you have an issue on this @ your repo?

Comment: Hi Piotr, your answer was excellent and helpful but I made the tough decision to award the answer to Zach since his example library was the thing that started this whole question off in the first place. That said, your A-Frame stack overflow answers are amazing and have helped me out of many tough spots. I hope to have the chance to ask / accept more answers soon.

Comment: Hi @KieranF. thank You for Your kind words :) Zach answer is way more detailed for your case, I was thinking about a more "general" feel :)